# My WP-Admin is showing a blank screen

Tags: wp-admin

When I tried to open the `WP-Admin` of my website, it is showing the blank screen. The `Wp-login.php` is opening but after the login, it is showing the blank screen.

So, I first moved my files and DB from the server to my localhost.

Then, I renamed the `plugins` folder to `plugins_old`.

After then, I replaced the copies of everything except the `wp-config.php` file and the `/wp-content/` directory with fresh copies from the download. This will effectively replace all of your core files without damaging your content and settings.

And then when I opened the wp-admin, it showed me to update the database and after updating the database my `wp-admin` opened and I am able to work.

In this, by replacing all the files except the `wp-config.php` file and the `/wp-content/` directory, Can I remove the particular set of files to open `wp-admin`?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: just share me url

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel, I have solved the problem and In this, by replacing all the files except the wp-config.php file and the /wp-content/ directory, Can I remove the particular set of files to open wp-admin?

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel, Can you please help me with the answer?

Comment: yes you can change it admin files make sure same version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Renamed the plugins folder to plugins_old.

Second, Replaced the copies of everything except the wp-config.php file and the /wp-content/ directory with fresh copies from the download. This will effectively replace all of your core files without damaging your content and settings.

I hope this will solve the problem.